# CoreData isn't showing query criteria

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am printing out SQLite queries from CoreData in my app, but the values are displaying as `?` and I am not sure why, here's an example:

`CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM Z_3WORKOUT WHERE Z_3SETS1 = ? AND Z_4WORKOUT = ?`